# Having YES/NO user interface buttons redirect to a link when clicked

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Is it possible to disguise the YES button after an alert so that when clicked it goes to a google drive folder location that has just been created e.g.

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   var response = ui.alert('Your CSV file has been saved in your Google drive', 'Do you wan to go to that file location?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

   // Process the user's response.
 if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
   var folder = DriveApp.createFolder('test');
   folder.getUrl()

 }
```

I am having trouble with the last line of the code, i can't figure out how to get the YES button, such that when clicked, opens a new window to that google drive location.

For context here is where the unique folder is created

```
function saveAsCSV() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var date = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(3,2).getValue();
  var time = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(4,2).getValue();
  var site = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,2).getValue();
  // iterate through all sheets in the spreadsheet and rename them according to cell B2
  for( var j = 0 ; j < sheets.length; j++) {
    var sourceSheet = sheets[j];
    // get contents of cell B2
    var newSheetName = sourceSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
    // rename sheet
    sourceSheet.setName(newSheetName);
  }
  // create a folder from the named SNOWSURVEYS with date
  var folder = DriveApp.createFolder('SNOWSURVEYS' + '_' + date + '_'+ site);
    // append ".csv" extension to the sheet name
    fileName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() + ".csv";
    // convert all available sheet data to csv format
    var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName);
    // create a file in the Docs List with the given name and the csv data
    folder.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this sample script? In order to make users redirect to the folder URL, I propose the use of `HtmlService`. This script displays a dialog box with yes/no buttons. When user pushes yes, a folder is created and move to the folder in user's browser.

At first, please run `openDialog()`. By this, you can see a dialog box on Spreadsheet.

This is a sample script, if you want to change the style, please modify it.

#### Sample script :

```
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>Your CSV file has been saved in your Google drive</p><p>Do you wan to go to that file location?</p><form><input type="button" value="yes" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(go).getUrl()" /><input type="button" value="no" onclick="google.script.host.close()" /></form><script>function go(url) {open(url, "_blank");}</script>');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'sample');
}

function getUrl(){
  var folder = DriveApp.createFolder('test');
  return folder.getUrl();
}
```

#### HTML in above script

```
<p>Your CSV file has been saved in your Google drive</p>
<p>Do you wan to go to that file location?</p>
<form>
    <input type="button" value="yes" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(go).getUrl()" />
    <input type="button" value="no" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
</form>
<script>
    function go(url) {
        open(url, "_blank");
    }
</script>
```

[image]

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

In following script, If the folder with the foldername is existing, it opens the existing folder. If the folder is not existing, the folder with foldername is created. In order to use this script, please modify `getUrl()`.

```
function getUrl() {
  var foldername = "test"
  return function(foldername){
      var f = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);
      return f.hasNext() ? f.next().getUrl() : DriveApp.createFolder(foldername).getUrl();
  }(foldername);
}
```

Comment: That's great, however, if the folder was already created prior to this step, how do i get the yes button to go to that folder? i.e. when you click yes, it doesn't need to create the folder 'test', because it was already done in a separate function prior.

Comment: Thanks that would work if the foldername is known and unique. However, my mistake, i should have provided a bit more context to this problem. Everytime the script runs it creates a new folder in Drive with a unique name. Therefore i cannot use a hardcoded name in the script to find the folder, it needs to be a variable of some sort.
I have updated the question to provide some more context

Comment: @Gramps You want to create one new folder with other name every time when the script is run. Is my understanding correct? I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Gramps If you want to use ``saveAsCSV()`` as an action by clicking, please modify as follows. 1. Modify from ``<input type="button" value="yes" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(go).getUrl()" />`` to ``<input type="button" value="yes" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(go).saveAsCSV()" />`` in HTML. 2. Add ``return folder.getUrl();`` to the last line of ``saveAsCSV()``.

Comment: Thats great!! I just called on the HTML service using an openDialogue() function that is outside the saveAsCSV function so that when clicked it would do the function saveAsCSV(). Otherwise, if it was run inside, it would keep creating new identical folders when clicking YES.
Thanks for your help and patience, very much appreciated.